# Conflict in IP address of WiFi AP and Ethernet Static configurations

Tags: linux, routing

I have an IOT device running Linux that has Wifi Access Point and Ethernet interfaces.
- WiFi Access Point is used for WEB server that listens on IP 172.16.0.1.
- Ethernet can be configurable to Static IP

The problem I have, is when configuring Ethernet's Static IP gateway to 172.16.0.1, the WEB Server is not accessible via the WiFi anymore.

I wonder what is the proper configuration that will solve my problem? and how it should be implemented?

Thanks

Comment: What is the configuration of the rest of the ethernet network? What is the gateway on this network?

Comment: This are the Static IP settings of ethernet, it has connection to internet:      IP - 172.16.2.221
Subnet Mask – 255.255.248.0
Gateway – 172.16.0.1
DNS – 172.16.0.1

Comment: So why have you put the same IP on the wifi interface of the IOT device? That is bound to clash, I would have thought.

Comment: The IP of the WiFi AP was chosen long time ago, and this device is in a production for long time. now we bumped into a client that needs this static IP configurations that i described. 
I wonder if there is any routing configuration that i can do to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your IOT device is setting up a separate network and is hard-coded to use 172.16.0.1. If this is the case it is only going to work if your ethernet network does **not** use an overlapping subnet. It looks like your ethernet network uses 172.16.0.0/21 and this does overlap.

If you cannot change the settings on the IOT device then you will need to change the subnet on the ethernet network.

Comment: Isn't there a way to handle such overlapping subnet by configuring NAT over the WiFi AP network, or some kind of iptable rule that will not forward from one interface to another?